# Placing imported sheet into a sheet named data and be placed at the respective columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have asked a question regarding on how do I import the data in the respective columns. I received helped and the code works when it is imported into sheet1 which is where my import file button is located.
However, when I change with activesheet to with worksheets("RawData"), the imported file data will not be placed in the respective columns.
For example, file A will go to column A and column B while file B will go to column C and column D.

```
Sub ImportFiles()

    'Declare a variable as a FileDialog object.
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim path As String
    Dim filename As String
    
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant
    With fd
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        'Set the initial path to the C:\ drive.
        .InitialFileName = ActiveWorkbook.path
        'Add a filter that includes  the list.
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Text Files", "*.txt", 1
        'The user pressed the button.
        If .Show = -1 Then
        
            For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
                path = Left(vrtSelectedItem, InStrRev(vrtSelectedItem, "\"))
                filename = Right(vrtSelectedItem, Len(vrtSelectedItem) - InStrRev(vrtSelectedItem, "\"))

                Call Importfile(path, filename)
            Next vrtSelectedItem
        Else
        End If
    End With

    Set fd = Nothing

End Sub
```

```
Sub Importfile(path As String, filename As String)

    Dim Target      As Range
    Dim C           As Long
    
   'Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Sheet1")).Name = "RawData"
   'ActiveSheet.Name = filename
    On Error Resume Next
    With Worksheet("RawData")
        C = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If C > 1 Then C = C + 1
        Set Target = .Cells(1, C)
        With .QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & path & filename, _
                              Destination:=Target)
            .Name = filename
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = False
            .AdjustColumnWidth = False
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = xlWindows
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
            .TextFileOtherDelimiter = vbTab
            .TextFileDecimalSeparator = "."
            .TextFileThousandsSeparator = " "
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the On Error Resume Next line. It is preventing you from seeing the error with  `Worksheet("RawData")` which should be `WorksheetS`

Comment: I have change the error to worksheets and have removed On error resume next. There is no error being prompted but i cant get second file to be imported to "rawdata"

Comment: Include in your question the code that calls that subroutine twice.

Comment: Did u mean the import function?

Comment: The code works for me so all I can suggest is adding a line `MsgBox .SelectedItems.Count & " Items Selected"` after 'If .Show = -1` Then' to check you have selected more than 1 item.